# Return Unauthorized (401) only when calling from code (c#)

Tags: c#, authentication, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-401

**UPDATE**

As @Alexandru Clonțea suggested, I checked the fiddler log and found:

In both success or fail cases, there are actually 2 requests being sent. The first request are mostly the same for both cases, it's something like:

```
    GET http://myservice.com/handler?param1=something&param2=somethingelse HTTP/1.1
    Authorization: Basic xxxxxx
    Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, 
    text/javascript, text/xml
    User-Agent: RestSharp/100.0.0.0
    Host: myservice.com
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The response for them are the same, which is:

```
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Location: /handler/?param1=something&param2=somethingelse
    Date: Sat, 08 Sep 2018 01:50:16 GMT
    Content-Length: 115

    <a href="/handler/?param1=something&param2=somethingelse">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

I have noticed that it always try to redirect the call to ***/handler/?param1=something&param2=somethingelse***, and that's because of the setup of the server code. it's actually working as expected. The difference is in the second request. The second request of the failure case (which is the c# code) ***doesn't have the authorization header*** and that's why it failed. Now, my question will be, why does the second request miss the authorization header? How can I fix it? Below is an example of the failed request:

```
GET http://myservice.com/handler/?param1=something&param2=somethingelse HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, 
text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/100.0.0.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: myservice.com
```

**Backgroud:**
I have a service written in GO deployed on a server. It requires a basic authentication. For example, I can call it successfully with the following request:

```
GET /handler/? 
param1=something&param2=somethingelse HTTP/1.1
> Host: myservice.com
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxx
> User-Agent: RestClient/5.16.6
> Accept: */*
```

The request above is made by a rest api client tool (like postman), and it's working fine. It's also working fine if I call it from a browser.

**Problem:**
Now, I try to make the same call to the same service using c# code, and I have it as:

```
// pass cert validation
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
var auth = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Authorization = auth;

var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result; // don't need async
```

But in this case, I am getting Unauthorized (401) back. I have checked into the actually request that was sent by the code, it had exactly the same authorization header as the one shows above (**Authorization: Basic xxxxxx**, and the xxxxxx is the same as above) and same uri as well. Actually, everything it sent looks the same as when I used the rest api client tool, but it was just failed in code.

when I check the log on the server side, I see the log below when it returns 401:

> [GIN-debug] redirecting request 301: /handler --> /hanlder/?param1=something&param2=somethingelse

but I don't see this log when the call is from the rest api client tool (or browser)

As you may know from the log, the server-side code is using the go gin framework. But since it works fine in other cases, I don't think it's a problem with the server-side code.

Back to the C# code, I have tried to use the **HttpWebRequest** with **NetworkCredential** instead of the **HttpClient**, and I also try to use **client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = auth**, but I was still getting the same error.

I am wondering if someone has seen this before or could help? It will be really appreciated.

Comment: try var auth = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", username + ":" + password);

Comment: Have you tried RestSharp? For me it's become the #1 way to consume REST, sometimes the build in HttpClient failed for me. Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7N5G4D

Comment: @SilentTremor I have tried that too, same error...

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea Just tried that, and same error...

Comment: Can you post a (client-side) fiddler dump of a failing and a working request? - with data anonymized of course.

Comment: `handler` vs `hanlder`. Explain please.

Comment: @spender that was just a typo, I change the name for security purpose

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea please see the update above

Comment: I'm guessing the working one is from Postman? If so, you can try the pro option of copy pasting the code it generates/probably uses internally as seen in response/UserAgent : https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets :)

Comment: Have you tried changing the Encoding to `UTF8Encoding`?

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea tried that already. same issue. I think the problem is how to make the second request sent with authorization header...

Comment: @machariadev yes, and same error

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I can modify the request to be ***http://myservice.com/handler/?param1=something&param2=somethingelse*** so that no redirection is needed. Thus, it will be correctly authorized.

But still, haven't figure out how to make the second request to be sent with the authorize header yet.